# Can't cast MockUnit to String with mockneat

Tags: java, string, casting, data-generation, random-data

Try to use my own `Enum` like `mock` with help of library `mockneat`. But the problem is that I can't take `string` value from `MockUnit` object for my right working of switch loop.

It's my `Enum`:

```
public enum SubType {

    ROUTER("router"),
    SERVER("server"),

    private final String value;

    SubType(final String newValue) {
    value = newValue;
    }

    public String getValue() {
    return value;
    }
}
```

And it's my `Build` class, where I try to use custom values from `SubType`:

```
public class Build {

private MockNeat mockNeat = MockNeat.threadLocal();
private ArrayList<String> group = new ArrayList<>();

public void addToList() {

    group.add("All Devices");
    group.add("All Groups");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        MockUnit subType =  mockNeat.from(SubType.class).map(SubType::getValue);

//EDITED:
//For example there are sout(subType) = "router"

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String json = mockNeat.reflect(Build.class)
                .field("group", constructGroupField(subType, group))
                .map(gson::toJson)
                .val();

        System.out.println(json);
    }
}

private ArrayList<String> constructGroupField(MockUnit subType, ArrayList<String> group) {

    //System.out.println(subType);
    //Output: net.andreinc.mockneat.abstraction.MockUnit$$Lambda$22/902830499@740773a3
    //But how I can get there my string like "router" or ""server"
    //How I can cast MockUnit to String value?

//EDITED:
// And there it can be already sout(subType)= "server"
    switch (subType.toString()) {

        case "router":
            group.add("All AAA");
            break;
        case "server":
            group.add("All BBB");
            break;
    }

    return group;
}
```

}

The main goal is to, depending on which string be in the `subtype` field, output the corresponding `json` file

UPDATED:

The final `Json` file, that I want to produce:

```
{
    "product": "a",
    "group": "router"
}
```

Another situation:

```
private String someMethod() {

        MockUnitInt localId = mockNeat.ints().range(5000, 35_000);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

        return mockNeat.reflect(someEntity.class)
                       .field("deviceLocalID", localId.mapToString())
                       .field("localID", localId.mapToString())
                       .map(gson::toJson)
                       .val();

    }
```

Even the `localId` was a `final` field in class, all time when something refer to it, it's give random value each time. Can't understand what wrong with that..

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is to change the switch line to:

```
switch (subType.val().toString())
```

The idea is that any `MockUnit` is not returning any value until you explicitly call `val()` on it.

But it's still not clear for me what you want to achieve? How do you want your final json to look like ?

PS: I might help, I am the author of MockNeat.

Comment: Thank you, with using `val()` method, I could take `String` value, from my var. But the problem is still in value of MockUnit object. I edited the answer.

Comment: @SpikeJohnson Show me how your end JSON will look like in the end (a mock) and I might be able to help you more. Only from the code, I am not sure I understand in what direction you are going.

Comment: I edited the question, did you ask about that? In other project, i watching the same, even a variable, which I want make random, is a final, all time, when I appeal to it - the new random result..

Comment: I solved the problem with good old `Random`, but you library could help me with my task more elegantly.

Comment: I'm added the same other situation.